# JS get multiple files from upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I'm trying to show multiple files that are uploaded however my console log of preview is blank. What am I missing here?

```
function readURL(input) {
            var preview = '';
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                $(input.files).each(function (index) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        preview += '<div class="image">';
                        preview += '<img src="' + e.target.result + '">';
                        preview += '</div>';
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[index]);
                });
                console.log(preview);
                $('.preview').html(preview);
            }
        }

        $("#logos").change(function () {
            readURL(this);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `preview` is still `''` when you log it to the console. This is because the `FileReader` "load" action is asynchronous, hence why you have to attach an `onload` handler to it. Try putting the `console.log` *inside* of the `onload` function.

```
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            $(input.files).each(function (index) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    preview += '<div class="image">';
                    preview += '<img src="' + e.target.result + '">';
                    preview += '</div>';
                    console.log(preview);
                    $('.preview').html(preview);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[index]);
            });
        }
```

In other words, the `onload` function doesn't trigger until some arbitrary time *after* you do `reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[index])`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the async `FileReader`, you can use the sync `URL.createObjectURL` instead, it will do you better

```
function readURL(input) {
  var preview = '';
  var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    $(input.files).each(function (index, file) {
      preview += '<div class="image">';
      preview += '<img src="' + URL.createObjectURL(file) + '">';
      preview += '</div>';
    });
    console.log(preview);
    $('.preview').html(preview);
  }
}

$("#logos").change(function () {
  readURL(this);
});
```